# Saving .doc files makes word crash

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, crash, office365, microsoft

Every old .doc file i have causes word (office 365, latest version) to crash istantly when saving.

Just open a .doc > save as > desktop > crash

Libreoffice writer can open and save them correctly.

What is going on?

Comment: What does Event Viewer say? Are you saving them as newer docx files? What happens when you save them to a different folder? Add all requested info to your question using the EDIT button.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This has been reported with version 2305 with .doc files generated by third-party programs. I have not experienced it and have tried both existing .doc files generated by Word and new .doc files generated by an earlier version of Word.

Answer (score -1):

From [File Extension Search](https://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/doc): "The DOC file extension is related to Microsoft Word and released by Microsoft Corporation in its Word version of 1997 to **2003**."

Since new version of Microsoft *Office* no longer support the uncompressed .doc format, you have a few choices:

1. Save the .doc file you opened **in .docx format** in the MS Word *Save as...* dialog.
2. [Find](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=31791), download, install and [activate](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-activate-office-2003/75d9cfde-23ae-475b-9fd1-b78a6f724e63) a 2003 or earlier version of MS *Office*. *This might take some effort.*
3. Continue to use free [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) to open, edit and save in .doc format, as you have done.

   For those unfamiliar with the available formats, the dialog below shows [*some* of those formats](https://www.file-extensions.org/libreoffice-writer-file-extensions); the *File* menu also has *Export as...* EPUB and PDF (with attributes such as author and title easily edited).

[image: LibreOffice Writer formats]